# Adding Apache xml-rpc library without .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jar

I have missed how to do this somewhere in learning Java, but when I want to add a library to my java project in eclipse, like the Apache xml-rpc that can be downloaded here: http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/ws/xmlrpc/

After downloading it I get a .zip file with the following structure:

.settings
client/
common/
dist/
server/
src/
.classpath
.project
I don't know what to do from here. I don't see a .jar file. I tried to convert it to a .jar, but couldn't get any success.

Steps taken to figure out on my own
Step 1) Numureous google searches
Step 2) Searches on here at stackoverflow
Step 3) Read all parts of Packaging programs in Jar files which can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/ on oracle

I still don't understand how to add this to my project and start using it

Comment: The link to **Apache xml-rpc** that you have provided is obsolete, it can now be found at this [link](http://archive.apache.org/dist/ws/xmlrpc/sources/apache-xmlrpc-3.1.3-src.zip), in case someone stumbles upon this question, like I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add it to your project, add it *as* a project using the Import Existing Projects wizard.  Then add that project to your own's Java Build Path.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it is the correct thing to do. This advances my question to ask why there are some many errors when I  import it. 

There is a package org.apache.ws....

That is missing.

How do I go about getting it?

Comment: I can only assume it's another Apache project for which you need to download a project or jars.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. This answer along with the question in context helped me run **Apache xml-rpc** from source instead of from `.jar` file.